# Код работает чуть больше суток и перестает работать и пропадают подключения к базе данных

Tags: python, mysql

Есть код на python в котором я запускаю сервер Flask для прослушивания вебхуков, которые я добавляю в очередь используя библиотеку Queue. Сначала я запускаю фоновый поток который собирает данные с сервиса, обрабатываю их и вставляю в базу данных. Так же во время обработки я добавляю данные в очередь обработки аудитов (истории изменений сущности), и запускаю поток который обрабатывает данные из этой очереди. После того когда добавились все данные я запускаю поток для обработки данных которые в очереди вебхуков. Почему то код работал больше суток и просто перестал обрабатывать все приходящие вебхуки. При этом в базе данных пропали подключения к ней(бывало что подключения оставались, но просто ничего не выполняли), так же создается много потоков у это кода хотя при обычной его работе было только 2 потока.

Создание подключения к бд

```
from mysql.connector import pooling
connection_pool = pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(
    pool_name="webhook",
    pool_size=5,
    pool_reset_session=True,
    host='host',
    user='user',
    password='password',
    database='database'
)
```

Часть кода:

```
def sql_insert(array_value):
    try:
        with connection_pool.get_connection() as connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()

            for entity_key, entity_item in array_value.items():
                # какая то обработка 

                query = insert_query(entity_key, arr_item)
                cursor.executemany(query, array_items)

                if audit_flag:
                    for one_id in id_item:
                        audit_queue.put((one_id, entity_key))
                        # Добавляем элементы в очередь

                # Обработка
                        
                cursor.executemany(query_link, link_item_one_entity)
                connection.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        send_error_to_telegram(e, "webhook")
    finally:
        pass
        # По завершении блока with соединение будет возвращено в пул автоматически


webhook_queue = queue.Queue()
audit_queue = queue.Queue()

def webhook_handler():
    while True:
        webhook_item = webhook_queue.get()
        # Получить элемент из очереди, блокируется до получения элемента
        try:
            # Обрабатываем элемент здесь
            webhook_body(webhook_item)
        except Exception as ex:
            send_error_to_telegram(ex, "webhook")
        finally:
            # Сообщить очереди, что обработка элемента завершена
            webhook_queue.task_done()


def audit_handler():
    while True:
        # Получить элемент из очереди, блокируется до получения элемента
        audit = audit_queue.get()

        try:
            # Обрабатываем элемент здесь
            audit_insert(audit)
        except Exception as ex:
            send_error_to_telegram(ex, "webhook")
        finally:
            # Сообщить очереди, что обработка элемента завершена
            audit_queue.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    thread_add = threading.Thread(target=data_processing)
    worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=webhook_handler)
    worker_thread.daemon = True
    # worker_thread.start()
    thread_add.start()

    audit_thread = threading.Thread(target=audit_handler)
    audit_thread.daemon = True
    audit_thread.start()
    worker_thread.start()

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: Если у вас фоновый поток висит с открытым подключением и долго простаивает сервер может разорвать соединение по таймауту, а клиентское приложение об этом не знает. Попробуйте переподключаться к БД.